# Setup jinput maven project

Tags: java, maven, jinput

I need a maven project via which I will be able to retrieve signals from my joystick. I set it up, by calling `mvn package` command I'm building JAR file. But there are some problems with jinput native libraries. I added dependency for jinput 2.0.6 version and it automatically putting native libraries(.dll, .so and .jnilib files) to classpath(to root inside the jar file). Jinput libs are JNI libraries. But I couldn't load this file. By current solution I'm running my jar file with this JVM argument:

```
java -jar jinput-project.jar -Djava.library.path=/home/usr/jinput-projects/jinputlibs
```

jinputlibs is an external folder where are jinput libs.
How can I resolve this problem?
How can I use the libraries inside the jar file?
Can I resolve this problem by maven(I mean by using .pom file)?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the DLLs directly and include them in your library as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783053/how-can-i-build-and-run-my-gradle-project-when-it-needs-binary-library-files-j/50612473#50612473)